# Android get current date and show it in TextView

Tags: android, date

I do not know what is wrong with code below -

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    String dt;
    Date cal = (Date) Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    dt = cal.toLocaleString();
    tv.setText(dt.toString());

}
```

Comment: What do you suspect to be wrong or what error do you encounter?

Answer (score 30):

I suggest:

```
long date = System.currentTimeMillis(); 

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM MM dd, yyyy h:mm a");
String dateString = sdf.format(date);   
tvDisplayDate.setText(dateString);
```

which displays in the following example format

`Mon Jan 5, 2009 4:55 PM`

You can use whatever format you want - options can be found [at Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 15):

use this code:

```
tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);


    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    yy = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mm = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    dd = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // set current date into textview
    tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
    // Month is 0 based, just add 1
            .append(yy).append(" ").append("-").append(mm + 1).append("-")
            .append(dd));
```

Answer (score 5):

Below solution might help -

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

updateDisplay();

private void updateDisplay() {
    mDateDisplay.setText(
        new StringBuilder()
        // Month is 0 based so add 1
        .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
        .append(mDay).append("-")
        .append(mYear).append(" "));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a TextClock as it will handle updates for you. For more info here is the documentation [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html) . [AnalogClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AnalogClock.html) and [DigitalClock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DigitalClock.html) can also be useful if your objective is just to display current time and date

```
 <TextClock
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:format24Hour="MMM,yyyy\n\thh:mm"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    SimpleDateFormat dfDate_day= new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String dt="";
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    data=dfDate_day.format(c.getTime());
    tv.setText(dt);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
tv.setText(currentDateandTime);
```

this is the way how i do it

Answer (score 1):

note*:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

// Donot import "import java.sql.Date;"

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
String ct = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
tv.setText(ct);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to generate a toast which is displaying current time on a button click then use this code.

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            min = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            int ds = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
            if(ds==0)
            AM_PM="pm";
            else
            AM_PM="am";

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+hour+":"+min+AM_PM, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
System.out.println("Currrent Date Time : "+formattedDate);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");    
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());    
tv.setText(currentDateandTime);
```