# Android - Getting date into textview

Tags: android, android-date

First of all let me say that yes, I've researched this quite a lot and used a variety of solutions but nothing is working.

So I'm trying to get yesterday's date into a textview. I'm using this code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MMMM/d");
String strDate = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
tvDate.setText(strDate);
```

(I know this returns today's date, but at this point I'm just trying to get anything)

What happens is once I get from the previous activity to this one it immediately shuts down. If I comment the 3 lines in the middle and setText to a random string like "bla bla", the activity runs and displays it correctly. Android Studio is not displaying any errors in there so I have zero idea what's going on.

I've tried all the solutions in the following posts, all unsuccessfully, so I can only imagine there's some configuration I'm missing.
1 - [Android get current date and show it in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934661/android-get-current-date-and-show-it-in-textview)
2 - [Get current time and date on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/get-current-time-and-date-on-android)
3 - [Display the current time and date in an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271131/display-the-current-time-and-date-in-an-android-application)

I've also checked some Youtube videos but none had the answer.

Can you help ?

Comment: I guess that the problem is in your `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: you wrote one `d`, is this right since it is possible that the day is of two numbers

Comment: In the Android Monitor you should have the stack trace to see what exception is thrown. Please post that, or provide more info on the activity you have this code in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it works fine for me, returning `2017/April/16`. Make sure that your `import` statements at the top of your class-file are correct. They should be:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
```

To get yesterday's date, add the following line:

```
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
```

Comment: that was it! My imports were `import android.icu.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import android.icu.util.Calendar;`  that were added automatically by Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Main{

public static void main(String ar[]){
Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();

System.out.println("Today's date= "+cal.getTime());
//subtracting a day
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
System.out.println("Yesterday's date= "+cal.getTime());

}

}
```